# How many "_-wing" spaceship models exist in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars

We know about the classics X-wing, Y-wing, A-wing, B-wing, etc... These "wings" are present in most, if not all, the films. But do any others exists like E-wing, K-wing, V-Wing, U-wing, etc? How many of these starships are there? One for every letter?

Comment: Really, since they took out all the English letters from the movies, the roman letter designation makes no sense in Star Wars anymore.

Comment: Apparently there exists other star fighters like the [C-wing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/C-wing) and the [V-wing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Alpha-3_Nimbus-class_V-wing_starfighter/Canon). Presumably in-universe this covers from A to Z but I don't know if the full range has ever been shown.

Comment: 26, we assume....

Comment: The V-wing is present at the end of Revenge of the Sith. The U-wing is present in Rogue One. K-wing is present in the EU only.

Comment: And don't forget that the X on an X-wing is formed by the... S foils.

Comment: This could get weird very fast if the Star Wars universe had emoji.

Comment: There's the infamous GL-Wing. It's a fighter that notoriously won't shoot first

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Canon Appearances:**

- A-Wing (ROTJ)
- B-Wing (ROTJ)
- D-Wing (Clone Wars Cartoon)

  - Technically a Droid, not a fighter.
- U-Wing (RO)
- V-Wing (ROTS)
- X-Wing (ANH)
- Y-Wing (ANH)

**Extended Universe / Legends Canon**

- C-Wing (d20 RPG example)
- E-Wing (EU Books)
- I-Wing (KOTOR cut content)
- K-Wing (Rogue Squadron Comics)
- T-Wing (Star Wars: TIE Fighter)
- H-Wing (FFG Stay on Target sourcebook, originally from West End Games Star Wars RPG)

**Notes**
There are actually a bunch of different ships called a V-Wing in the EU, most probably from before Lucas made an offcial instance of the craft in ROTS

Comment: +1 Awesome list. Can you provide an example image where applicable?

Comment: @JohnP The only references to a M-wing I could find were specifically calling it the "M-Class", so it doesn't technically fit. There's a few other *-Class ships out there.

Comment: @JohnP, with regards to the L-Wing. Are you referring to the S-250 Chela-class starfighter? The only evidence I can find of an L-Wing is a picture for that ship with the filename Lwing. Do they mention the vehicle's name on screen or in the comics?

Comment: @devsman I can grab some images later this evening.

Comment: @ench - I think you're right, I couldn't confirm they were 'wing' class ships. :)

Comment: I’m pretty certain there was a Z-wing somewhere in one of the books. I seem to recall  Bespin Cloud City patrol craft. Possibly atmospheric only.

Comment: The T-Wing also features in the games: X-Wing vs TIE Fighter, X-Wing Alliance, Jedi Knight: Mysteries of the Sith and Star Wars Galaxies

Comment: @Tonny this is probably what you are remembering: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Z-wing.

Comment: @Tonny you might also be thinking of the Z-95 Headhunter, which was featured in the Star Wars: TIE Fighter game starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Z-95_Headhunter. It's like an X-Wing, but with two fixed wings only, no s-foils. In my head, I called it the "z-wing" because of its similarity to the X-wing, and the fact that it had a Z in its name.

Comment: For some reason, its not letting me embed images, only link to them.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That’s it. It was an ‘ugly’, that I remember know and Z95 rings a bell too.

Comment: Rather than embedding images, may I suggest linking to the relevant Wookiepedia pages? http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/RZ-1_A-wing_interceptor

Comment: One scene towards the end of KotOR has a shuttle identified (I think in-game, certainly in files) as a "G-Wing". I don't know if you want to count that because, well, it's a shuttle and not a fighter.

Comment: You'll find quite a few images under the BGG pages for all the models FFG make for their minis games. https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/103885/star-wars-x-wing-miniatures-game/expansions