# Where is this triangular-shaped space station from?

Tags: object-identification, space-station

I came across this image on Facebook. It looks similar to *Deep Space Nine*. A reverse image search on Google revealed that the station is from an old Chinese television show. Now I am wondering does anyone know the name of this show?

[image: unknown triangular space station]

Comment: http://www.hxnews.com/news/dmyx/dmzx/dhxw/201707/24/1264597.shtml - My Chinese is rusty, but it seems to be a show called [Dijia Ottoman](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/The-Dijia-Ottoman-universe-Superman/870863130.html)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This is Space Station Delta from the Japanese series [*Ultraman Tiga*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraman_Tiga) (1996), obviously part of the Ultraman franchise. Specifically, the shot is taken from episode 7, timestamp 1'55:

[image: triangular spaceship]

For the record, it's part of the Terrestrial Peaceable Consortium fleet, the TPC being an organization "ensuring peace on Earth", partly by fighting creatures from outer space with the GUTS teams (Global Unlimited Task Squad), who got reassigned to combat after originally being a rescue/investigation branch.

---

When Google queries like `Chinese TV shows in space` returned nothing relevant, I reverse-imaged the picture, Google-translated [this result](https://www.itsfun.com.tw/%E5%9C%B0%E7%90%83%E5%92%8C%E5%B9%B3%E8%81%AF%E5%90%88%E7%B5%84%E7%B9%94/wiki-6587776-9904656), learned that the ship was called Space Station Delta. Browsing the *Ultraman* wiki taught me that it is lead by [Omi Yanase](https://ultra.fandom.com/wiki/Omi_Yanase), who only had one appearance in *Ultraman Tiga*, so I fast-forwarded this episode to confirm whether the ship was from there.

Comment: *Does anyone know where this picture is from?*  ***20+ year old Japanese franchise.  I've never seen it but used a bunch of ubiquitous, free tools to track down the people that do.  Here's the episode and timestamps it's from.***  28 minutes.  Internet, you amaze me.

Comment: *"This is space station Delta"* Get it, get it? Or, if the show's designer's didn't intend the visual pun they missed a great oportunity.

Comment: @dmckee It's triangular corridors in a triangular shape. No way it's accidental!

Comment: @dmckee The X-wings from Star Wars have X-shaped wings. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/173057/4918

Comment: Given that this season of Ultraman came out after DS9 started, one wonders if it was a shout out or homage...

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile "total ripoff" isn't to exclude either :-)

Comment: @b_jonas And the Y-wings are Y-shaped when viewed from the top.

Comment: @Angew And A-wings have a similar property, sure, but explain B-Wings to me...

Comment: @Chronocidal No can do (and it's always bothererd me).

Comment: @user1717828, You should comes to anime identification. When user find 20+ old anime related stuff with an unclear description and oddly specific keyword that yield thousand of result. It's a classic Jenayah.

Comment: @dmckee: Space Station Γ must be quite susceptible to breaking in two... Or was it already bent out of shape during construction?

Comment: @Chronocidal @Angew Fold in the B-wing's s-foils (smaller side wings). Spin it so that the tip of the main wing is at the top, and the gyro-cockpit at the bottom. Looks a *bit* like a lowercase 'b'. ...Best I've been able to come up with. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` ...Still would've made more sense as the T-wing, though.

Comment: @FeRD, Couldn't do T-Wing because it's used in model numbers for other craft.  The X-Wing is a T-65...

Comment: Why the bleep would the corridors to the central hub go the long distance to the corners rather than the short distance to the side midpoints? *[Desire paths?](https://www.theguardian.com/cities/2018/oct/05/desire-paths-the-illicit-trails-that-defy-the-urban-planners)*

Comment: @Harper To make a stronger structure due to it consisting of triangles, whereas joining to the midpoints would create weaker quadrangles?

Comment: @user21820 Space Station Γ may also have had quite a problem with radiation. ;)

Comment: @Angew it's possibly the upgraded version of the A-wing, so they just incremented the letter.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck at least in the games, the A wings came later than the B wings.